# conf/storm.yaml is not populated with values coming from config map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-storm

I am using Apache Storm Helm Chart https://github.com/G-Research/charts.

When the chart is installed, and connect to nimbus, conf/storm.yaml is not replaced with the one coming from config map, cf. https://github.com/G-Research/charts/blob/master/storm/templates/configmap.yaml#L10, created using config from values.yaml.
When printed, we have the default storm.yaml packaged with Apache Storm.

Any idea how to have conf/storm.yaml same as the one configured in configmap?

Comment: please show you values, and how you use them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/G-Research/charts as aforementioned.
The storm.yaml is set here: https://github.com/G-Research/charts/blob/master/storm/templates/configmap.yaml#L10
I see some volume mount related to configmap and storm config: https://github.com/G-Research/charts/blob/master/storm/templates/nimbus-statefulset.yaml#L49

Comment: Did found that the config were mounted on /conf instead STORM_FOLDER/conf. Thus, I answered my question